# Oracle Apex - Gantt Chart with multiple taks per row

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, gantt-chart, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently working with Gantt charts in Oracle Apex version 5.1.2. Does anyone know of a good Gantt chart plug-in that allows for multiple child tasks in a single row. The only Gantt chart plug-ins that I can find allow for only one child task per row.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At the moment I didn't work with gantt charts. I think apex still using anychart version of gantt. But, the new oracle jet charts have this functionality. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=multipleTasks

Comment: Thank you @romeuBraga for your response. Do you know how to implement Oracle Jet components into Oracle Apex 5.1? I have found some documentation online about how to create plugins for these components, but the code they use to create the each plugin seems very specific to the actual component that they are creating the plugin for and doesn't really apply to the gantt chart.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this problem. I think maybe you can create another question "How integrate Gantt Oracle Jet Chart in Apex" using the tag "oracle-jet" and apex tags. Maybe someone have this solution for you. Gantt and Map charts don't use Oracle JET in Application 5.1; as in earlier versions, these are driven by the AnyChart engine. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/5841/index-en.html

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you!